# openmp: race condition in for loop and critical section

Tags: openmp, race-condition

I'm getting unpredictable errors in my program when running with a lot of threads and am trying to find where the problem sits by inserting critical sections. Now I've got to the following

```cpp
void A::func()
{
 #pragma omp parallel for
 for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
  {
    #pragma omp critical
    results[i] = compute(i);
  }
}
```

This still gives me the problem that I'm trying to find. The only way I can get it to disappear is by removing the parallelisation of the `for` loop (not very desirable!).

Note that the `compute` function is complicated and actually uses some caches. I wouldn't be surprised if there is some problem in that code, but as the whole thing is now in a critical section, I can't understand what's going on.

The actual for loop that I'm trying to debug is at https://github.com/UCL/STIR/blob/49c65340a2116834fea6a9a5cb17f73eb4a6f259/src/scatter_buildblock/ScatterSimulation.cxx#L179-L198. The test version that still has the problem (close to the example above) is [here](https://github.com/KrisThielemans/STIR-1/blob/25fe894615534c1f16386b13fd8f231cd3d85673/src/scatter_buildblock/ScatterSimulation.cxx#L179-L194)

Note: I had first posted this in a more complicated scenario but I've deleted [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69600015/openmp-critical-section-inside-a-function-called-in-a-parallel-for-loop) as 1) my simple example there doesn't exhibit the problem and 2) this scenario is even more puzzling.

Some more info added. I'm trying this on Windows 10 with a Ryzen 9 5900. My test code shows occasional problems with gcc-8 and gcc-9 on WSL2/Ubuntu 20.04. (I observe no problems with VS 2019 on windows nor clang-13 on WSL2/Ubuntu 20.04, but that doesn't mean a lot I guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code snippet in question from github.

```
#ifdef STIR_OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:total_scatter) schedule(dynamic)
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(all_bins.size()); ++i)
    {
        const Bin bin = all_bins[i];
        const double scatter_ratio = scatter_estimate(bin);

#if defined STIR_OPENMP 
#  if _OPENMP >= 201107
#    pragma omp atomic write
#  else
#    pragma omp critical(ScatterSimulationByBin_process_data_for_view_segment_num)
#  endif
#endif
        viewgram[bin.axial_pos_num()][bin.tangential_pos_num()] =
                static_cast<float>(scatter_ratio);
        total_scatter += static_cast<double>(scatter_ratio);
    } // end loop over bins
```

These are the possible causes of your problem:

1. `scatter_estimate` is not threadsafe. Using `#pragma omp critical` before the function would have solved it if this is the case.
2. `bin.axial_pos_num()` or `bin.tangential_pos_num()` is not threadsafe. Please check these as well.
3. The result depends on the order of execution of your loop. If different `i` gives the same indices (i.e. `bin.axial_pos_num()` and `bin.tangential_pos_num()`) then different execution order may give different result, because you overwrite the same element of `viewgram` array in different order.
   Note that, if this is the case it may be a flaw in your algorithm.

Comment: thanks @laci. 1. Indeed, `scatter_estimate` might not be thread-safe, which is what I'm trying to find out. Putting it in `#pragma omp critical` didn't help. 2. `bin.*` are just read-access so should be fine, but using the `critical` section as opposed to `atomic write`  doesn't help. So I went even further and put the whole thing in a critical section, but that doesn't help either. I'll edit the post to make this clearer. Remains 3. In my case, relation between `i` and `bins` is unique, but I guess there could be something in my caches that depends on order (which would be a bug...).

Comment: Try your loop in reverse order (without OpenMP), if you got different result you have found your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Laci. Order it was! Looking closer at my code, I was sensitive to the common problem of `float` precision being insufficient. I hadn't seen that as for most of the numbers I test, dependence on order was really small, but apparently for some it wasn't! Going to `double` seems to have resolved this.